# RNN training metrics in python darts

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, metrics

I'm currently training a RNNModel using python darts. For comparing different trained models I want to extract the train_loss and val_loss from the fit method. How would I do this? I've read something about a metric collection but can't figure out how to use it.

This is my current code

```
from darts.models import RNNModel
from darts import TimeSeries

train = # training data as TimeSeries
model = RNNModel(model="LSTM", input_chunk_length=self.past_samples)
model.fit(train)
```

The loss is shown in the console during training but I don't know how to access it.

So far I've tried to find any docs online and asked bing chat and ChatGPT for help. However they told me to use `model.history.history["loss"]` which doesn't exist

Comment: This code is too generic, its missing imports, what DL framework are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As said I use darts https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.rnn_model.html